# WPF Get MouseHover Event from dynamic set ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mouseover

How can I get a `MouseOver` event from dynamic set `ListViewItems`?

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ListView" x:FieldModifier="public" ItemsSource="{Binding FileDataList}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="12">       
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Change date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" Width="Auto"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>            
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
fileDataList.Add(new FileData() { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename), Date = File.GetLastWriteTime(filename), Type = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename), Size = GetFileSize(filename) });
```

This are the lists:

```
public List<string> files = new List<string>();
private ObservableCollection<FileData> fileDataList = new ObservableCollection<FileData>();
```

Comment: Please write, what you want to do in MouseOver event...

Comment: I want to show a window which presents a preview of the file, where the mouse is over in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set following style in `ListView`'s resource:

```
 <ListView.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseEnter" />
          <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseLeave" />
       </Style>
 </ListView.Resources>
```

On the code behind use following code to determine currently hovered item.

```
private ListViewItem _currentItem = null;
private void ListViewItem_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (!Equals(_currentItem, item))
    {
        _currentItem = item;

        // code to update window 
    }
}

private void ListViewItem_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _currentItem = null;
}
```